# Get Owner of a file read from S3 using Nifi

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, apache-nifi, file-ownership

We have a flow that sends files from a windows directory to a S3 Bucket.
We use Nifi to get files from that bucket and we need to get the owner of the file.

I found "Include File Attributes" in ListFile processor but I can't find an equivalent in the processor ListS3.

Any ideas ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use below code sample to retrieve the owner details.

```
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata

// Initialize the S3 client
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient()

// Fetch the S3 object key from FlowFile attributes
def s3ObjectKey = flowFile.getAttribute('s3.object.key')

// Get the owner of the S3 object
def s3ObjectMetadata = s3Client.getObjectMetadata('your-s3-bucket-name', s3ObjectKey)
def owner = s3ObjectMetadata.getOwner()

// Set the owner as an attribute on the FlowFile
flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'file.owner', owner.toString())

return flowFile
```

Remember to adjust the script and configuration to match your specific requirements, including the S3 bucket name and the attribute names used in your NiFi data flow.

Comment: Thank you, what's the input of this script ? I don't have the property : s3.object.key in ListS3/FetchS3Object